# EMR 5.13: Spark 2.3.0 UI shows Executors remain alive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr

Ever since I've upgraded to `EMR 5.13`, I've been seeing strange metrics on the `Spark` & `YARN` *UIs*.

In this particular instance:

- `YARN` showed that process completed
  [image: YARN reports task completed]
- `Ganglia` shows that *cluster* has been *idle* since completion of last (118th) job
- `Spark` UI also tells that all my 118 tasks have been completed
    [image: All 118 jobs were completed]

Even so, `Spark` UI reports that all **`Executor`s are alive**, long (over 1 hr at time of writing) after the last *job* was completed.
[image: Executors are still alive with active tasks]

---

Could this be a UI glitch or there's something else going on?

Frameworks / Platform:

- `EMR 5.13`
- `Spark 2.3.0`
- `Hive 2.3.2`
- `Hadoop: Amazon 2.8.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One executor with active tasks in your screen is marked as Dead. It shows statistics at the moment of termination.

As you can see, executor #5 has processed 624 tasks before termination. Then yarn started a new executor #9 instead that completed 76 tasks